# How can I print key of an entity using NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In old datastore I can print key of an entity by

## old data store

q = MyDB.all()
q.filter("property", proertyValue)

getKey = q.get()
printKey = getKey.key # this will return string like agxkZXZ-c3l…

## NDB

q = MyNDB.query()
q = q.filter(MyNDB.property == propertyValue)

getKey = q.get()
printKey = getKey.key # it return id like 5066549580791808 but actually I want a key value

How can I print key value on NDB

Thank in avance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want the key printed. There are a couple options when it comes to key representation in ndb.

1) Get a websafe base64 encoded serialization of the string, like so:

```
printKey = getKey.key.urlsafe()
```

[link to docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe)

2) Or, if you would like a representation of the key like that using DB, you can actually get the DB key from the NDB key using `to_old_key()`:

```
printKey = getKey.key.to_old_key()
```

[link to docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_to_old_key)